# Move multiple sub folders to a different directory and keep the folder names

Tags: c#, file-io

Please could a C# expert help with a simple problem which for some strange reason I just can't seem to work out? I'm trying to move multiple sub folders in the current directory to a new directory and keep the subfolder name, see below:

```
public string currentDirectory = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOCALAPPDATA") + @"\Test\CurrentFolder\";

public string newDirectory = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOCALAPPDATA") + @"\Test\NewFolder\";

private void btnMoveFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(currentDirectory);
    try
    {
        foreach (string subCurrentDirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
        {
            Directory.Move(subCurrentDirectory, newDirectory);

        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        Log("Problem with moving the directory.");
    }
}
```

At the moment, I only seem to be able to move one folder instead of all of the them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: sooo... what is the _problem_ with the code you are using (apart from the formatting :))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want this:

```
Directory.Move(subCurrentDirectory, 
    Path.Combine(
        newDirectory, 
        Path.GetFileName(subCurrentDirectory)));
```

Comment: Hi Sehe, Your code worked a treat, thanks!  By the way, what's wrong with my formatting? :)  I've only been programming for 10 months in the evenings so any tips appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
DirectoryInfo subfolder = new DirectoryInfo(@"OLDPATH\DirectoryToMove");
subfolder.MoveTo(@"NEWPATH\DirectoryToMove");
```

Just make sure you include the name of the directory to move in both the old AND new filepaths.

In general DirectoryInfo and FileInfo are much more useful than Directory and File in most situations.